# Cypress: set timeout to custom command

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I have a custom command where I want to override the default timeout of 4 seconds. I tried setting the timeout in the command's code and in the tests that use it but with no success yet.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", () => {
  Auth.signIn(username, password)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Programmatically logged in as ' + username);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Error when login in: ', err));
})
```

I attempted the following:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", { timeout : 10000} () => {...}
```

and

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", () => {
  Auth.signIn(username, password)
    .then(({ timeout : 10000}) => {
        console.log('Programmatically logged in as ' + username);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Error when login in: ', err));
})
```

EDIT/UPDATE

I added async/await to the `Auth.signIn()` call and that makes the execution wait for that method to finish, but if it reaches the 4 seconds default timeout it makes  the test fail.
The best I could do was include all the test code inside the `then` of the `login` command.

```
it('Test that requires login', () => {
    cy.login().then(function (){
        cy.visit('/');
        //...
    });
})
```

Although the test waits for the login operation to finish, it fails if the timeout is reached before it is logged in.

Comment: Do you want a 10 seconds wait time?

Comment: If the reason for your timeout is the time needed for the form to finish it`s work, I suggest to target a key element at the follow up page, that you will need for testing and wait for it to be visible. It is not 100% full proof, but in most cases is a better practice.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal not exactly. The login operation takes between 3.5 to 8 seconds to finish, making the test flaky because when the login is completed before the 4 seconds timeout it passes, otherwise it doesn't

Comment: @RosenMihaylov thanks for the suggestion. The trick is that in the app, when a not logged in user navigates to the home page it gets redirected to the /login page, so I the login process must be completed even before the start of the test and the command `cy.visit`

Comment: @MauriR, in that case I would use `cy.get('loginFormElement').should('be.visible')` after `cy.visit()` and before the test starts

Comment: @RosenMihaylov I should have explained better, sorry. A logged in user is not redirected to the /login page when navigating to the home page, so the login process must be finished before the redirect takes place. If the app redirects to `/login` and after this the login process is finished (without using the UI, which is what the `cy.login` command does), the test continues in the login page instead of the home page and fails because it doesn't find the elements of the home page.

Comment: @MauriR in that case I would use `cy.visit(pageUrl)` at the end of the login function,or `cy.reload()` . This would ensure page rendering before test, if i assume correctly - that it will redirect it to the right page.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about `timeout` in Cypress's [**custom commands**](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax), but you could use a workaround by passing a **[default param](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)** into your custom command like so:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (waitTimer = 1000) => {
  Auth.signIn(username, password)
    .then(() => {
        cy.wait(waitTimer);
        console.log('Programmatically logged in as ' + username);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Error when login in: ', err));
})
```

**Note**: Beware that passing `timeouts` or arbitrarily waiting for an `x` amount of seconds **[is not considered good practice](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Unnecessary-Waiting)**. You should instead check for the `response's status` & assert it returns a `200` status or use [**route aliases**](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/spread.html#Examples).

**Example:**

```
......
.then(response => {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      cy.log('An error happened while logging in');
    }
```

Comment: Totally agree, Just as an extension - If it is a repeated default param, i place it in cypress.env.json and collect it from there

Comment: @RosenMihaylov oh I didn't think about that! Yes, placing the default param in the `cypress.env.json` is a nice idea!

Comment: @ManuelAbascal thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue because the `cy.wait(waitTimer)` is executed after the login operation and I need to wait it to complete, rather than wait a certain amount of time after. In my test I have the `cy.login()` command and after it a `cy.visit()`. I need the visit command to wait for the login but it doesn't. If I put a `async/await` in the command's code, the login is awaited but if it takes more than 4 seconds the test fails.

Comment: @MauriR have you trying using route aliases? https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/spread.html#Aliased-Routes

Comment: You could also log in via a `cy.request()` & assert the response status. You can check this recipe  https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/logging-in__xhr-web-forms/cypress/integration/logging-via-request-spec.js

Comment: @ManuelAbascal I haven't because the login state must be set before the visit command, so I am not waiting for a route navigation. Regarding the `cy.request()` command, I may have to investigate how to login to AWS Cognito using a POST request. It is easier to login using the Amplify framework though as in the code above.